# Application Context Menu in WPF with WindowStyle=None

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a very strange problem with a custom WPF window. The window is designed completely in WPF with WindowStyle=None and ResizeMode=NoResize. So I have to reimplement all the basic window handling stuff like moving, resizing and - here is the problem - the application context menu.

Currently I'm calling the context menu in the mouse-event of the app icon and application titlebar as follows:

```
POINT point=new POINT();
GetCursorPos(out point);
IntPtr handle=GetSystemMenu(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, false);
IntPtr hd=new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
int retvalue=TrackPopupMenu(handle, TPM_RETURNCMD, (int)point.X, (int)point.Y, 0, hd, new IntPtr());
PostMessage(hd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, retvalue, 0);
```

This is a code snipped you can find all over the net, looks like everyone is doing it this way.

However depending on the events I use to show the menu the following happens:

MouseUp:

- Right click on titlebar/app icon: Application context menu appears
- Doing another right click without moving the mouse: Somehow a right click event is generated inside the window (while the mouse still points on the titlebar).

Funny part: The Click is translated into the window by window.Left and window.Top. If I place the window correctly, I can open the context menu of a ListView inside of the window while the mouse still points to the tilebar.

MouseDown:

- Right mouse down on titlebar/app icon: Application context menu appears
- Right mouse up without moving the mouse: Same behaviour, a right click is generated inside of the window at Mouse position + window.Left/window.Top.

I've made a screenshot and measured the pixel distance to check if it's really window.Top/Left.

That's what I've done while trying to solve the problem:

- Tested dozens of changes to the Code snipped to show the context menu without effect
- I completely removed resize/move code from the window class, no change
- Played around with EventArgs.Handled, no change
- Enqueued the code snipped in the dispatcher instead of calling it directly in the event, no change

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to implement the context menu in the xaml of the custom window? If you are working with Templates you can already integrate it on there or use it in the CustomWindow.xaml

```
<'ControlName'.ContextMenu>    
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="FooRoot">
            <MenuItem Header="Foo" Command="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Foo2" Click="OnClick"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</'ControlName'.ContextMenu>
```

You can bind the command (maybe if you are working the the MVVM pattern) or make an event for it.

Comment: Yeah I could try to mimic the application context menu provided by windows with a custom implementation, but this would be a dirty hack, not a real solution. For example I'm using windowspager (not related to the problem here, tested on another machine) which extends the menu by options to move the window to other desktops - would be difficult to duplicate these.